# Post shows more content when edited than actually exists

Tags: support, code-formatting, specific-edit

Today, I wanted to edit the following question:
[Discord Global DM Wait Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69483907/discord-global-dm-wait-time)

I just wanted to change the format so that the post could be more descriptive. But when I was redirected to the edit, I noticed that the page displays more code in the edit than is actually there.

Is this some kind of error? I have already refreshed the page, cancelled the edit and closed Stack Overflow again and reopened it, no change to be seen.

**Original post:**

[image: There is only one line of code formatted text between Error and Code.]

- As seen it is not in the Python format.
- There is text between the two code "blocks".

**Edit page:**

[image: There is another line of code that starts inline with the code fence below Error heading.]

- The "Error" section shows the same code from "Code" again.
- If I insert `py` after "```", then the actual "Error" part is displayed in the correct "color", but just still with the content of "Code". If I remove everything up to the actual error message nothing happens.
- The arrows show what should actually only be seen while editing the post.

Comment: The text that starts *at the same line* as the code fence `\`\`\`` will ***not*** be part of the snippet, since it's supposed to be the syntax highlight suggestion.

Comment: @VLAZ But why is the text then displayed twice? When editing, the same code as for "Error" is again under "Code", although this should not be there at all, or do I understand you wrong?

Comment: The first line is starts with `while` after the `\`\`\``. The *second* line starts with `TypeError`. You see the *second* line, because it's the line *inside* the code fence. The first line is hidden because it's where the code fence starts and it's considered the syntax highlighting hint. Which isn't anything real but it's how the markdown parser works.

Comment: @Dominik That's because it's showing _where_ the error occured

Comment: @Nick I was not aware that the code that is in the same row as ``` is not posted, that makes sense then of course in the end. This author also asked the question several times and to show one line of the error I almost consider normal, if you do not know the correct formatting.

Comment: Related on MSE: [Can we warn users if the first line of a code block is silently discarded if placed on the same line as ```?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/350535/289905), and MSO: [Users frequently start code blocks on the same line as the triple backticks](/q/391467/4642212).